# how to copy only values to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy only the values over from one workbook where calculations are done to another that holds all data. I have tried using .Value and xlPasteSpecial, but I think I'm using them incorrectly. I have limited VBA experience and am not a programmer.

```
Sub Consolidate()


Dim fName As String, fPath As String, fPathDone As String
Dim lr As Long, NR As Long
Dim wbData As Workbook, wsMaster As Worksheet

'Setup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro execution
    Application.EnableEvents = False    'turn off other macros for now
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'turn off system messages for now

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BM Condition")    'sheet report is built into

With wsMaster
    If MsgBox("Clear the old data first?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Clear
        NR = 2
    Else
        NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1    'appends data to existing data
    End If

'Path and filename (edit this section to suit)
    fPath = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Test"            'remember final \ in this string"
    fPathDone = fPath & "Imported\"     'remember final \ in this string
    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir fPathDone                 'creates the completed folder if missing
    On Error GoTo 0
    fName = Dir(fPath & "*.xls*")        'listing of desired files, edit filter as desired

'Import a sheet from found files
    Do While Len(fName) > 0
        If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then              'don't reopen this file accidentally
            Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName)  'Open file

        'This is the section to customize, replace with your own action code as needed
            lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Find last row
            Range("P14:S" & lr).EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & NR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            wbData.Close False                                'close file
            NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1  'Next row
           ' Name fPath & fName As fPathDone & fName           'move file to IMPORTED folder
        End If
        fName = Dir                                       'ready next filename
    Loop
End With

ErrorExit:    'Cleanup
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True         'turn system alerts back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True          'turn other macros back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        'refreshes the screen
End Sub
```

I want only values from P14-S14. Can anyone assist with pulling only values from these cells?

Comment: `PasteSpecial` should work fine - what did you try?

Comment: i put it after .Range("A" & NR) that may be the wrong spot

Comment: `.Range("A" & NR).pastespecial xlvalues` should work but it must be on a new line after the Copy line.

Comment: i did not have it on a new line, thank you